# Get data from 2 tables sql in asp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve data "only from orders table" with condition orderid of orders = orderid of payment .

Below is my query,but it shows matching data from both tables

```
select * from order,payment where orders.orderid=payment.orderid;
```

orders table below

```
"name" 
"model"
"price"
"email" 
"phoneno" 
"billaddress" 
"address" 
"city" 
"state" 
"zipcode" 
"orderid" 
"date"
```

payment table below

```
"email" 
"cardno" 
"name" 
"transid" 
"date" 
"orderid"
```

"I want to retrieve all data only  from orders table ."

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select order.*
from order,payment
where orders.orderid=payment.orderid;
```

OR

```
select order.*
from order
inner join payment on orders.orderid=payment.orderid;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Melwin : This query will pull all the data from the orders table, which will include the email address as well as shown by @shady

select order.*
from order,payment
where orders.orderid=payment.orderid;

So I am not sure as to what do you mean by adding a where clause to get the row associated with the email ? Are you looking to pull data for a specified email id ? If so the u can add "and order.email Like '%abc@example.com%' at the end of your code. But if u need something specific let me know and I can help further.